# Why ArrayList with an initial size returns 0 for size?

Tags: java, arraylist

Why the last println prints out 0 rather than 80?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(80);
System.out.println(list.size());
```

Comment: That's not even `C#` man

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName - not sure why you decided to add C# tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have nothing in the ArrayList. ArrayList.size() returns the number of elements in the array, but your array has no elements.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't put anything in the collection - just reserved some space for things you will put in the collection.